# Newer (unity) question is listed after older questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

When I use the following filter (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity?filter=week&sort=hot) there is a question from 18 hours ago that is listed as last element in the list (and after older posts).

Changing the filter to month does not put it back on track.

[image]

Comment: I think I've seen this too, on meta. Maybe a bug in the redesigned new nav.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [hot sort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/213575), not new or active. The hotness score is accurate since it decays with time: newer questions are hotter, then it is ordered by score/views/answers and starts to decay.

You may use the [active sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity?filter=week&sort=active) or [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity?filter=week&sort=new).

Comment: Ok maybe you are right. I did not noticed that. But the "newest" and "active" options are disabled. I´m not sure why

Comment: @Jehof interesting... that might be a bug, through it's possible to just modify the url parameters as workaround.

Comment: Correction, is a bug.

Comment: @Jehof because it makes no sense to see "newest" or "active" questions limited to "today" or "this month". You need to select "All questions" on the left first.